# what's a good pattern for registering a Class to execute a specific task later on?

Tags: java, unit-testing, playframework, testng, mockito

I'm writing a test suite, and I'm thinking about how to mock certain request/response flows. For example, I want to test a method that makes multiple RESTful calls:

```
getCounts() {
  ...
  Promise<Integer> count1 = getCount1();
  Promise<Integer> count2 = getCount2();

  // returns a DataModel containing all counts when the Promises redeem
}

getCount1() {
  ...
  Request<Foo> request = new Request<Foo>();
  sendRequest(request);
  ...
}

getCount2() {
  ...
  Request<Bar> request = new Request<Bar>();
  sendRequest(request);
  ...
}

sendRequest(Request<T> request) {...}
```

However, each `getCount()` method creates a different `Request<T>` object, where `<T>` describes the type of request being made in regards to the count being retrieved. This means I can't simply "mock" the `sendRequest()` method since it is being called with a different type each time.

I was thinking about an approach where I register a "handler"... when `sendRequest()` is called, it determines which handler to call, and the handler would know the appropriate type of mock data to return. The registration would be something like storing the handler class type or an instance of the handler class along with the mock data it needs, and when `sendRequest()` is called, it would look for and invoke the correct handler.

However, I'm not sure if this a good pattern, and I'm wondering if there is a better way of approaching this problem. What is a good pattern for registering a Class or a particular method to execute a specific task later on?

Comment: Testing:  It's the #1 reason why `static` is _not_ your friend.

Comment: my hands are tied on this... `static` is a part of the codebase and I just have to work with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to answer without more context, but the general approach is to use Inversion Of Control (IOC). For example, put the `getCountXXX` methods into a class of their own, which may be a good idea for better reuse, readability, encapsulation, testability, etc:

```
public class CountFetcher {
  getCount1() { ... }
  getCount2() { ... }
}
```

The original code now gets an instance of `CountFetcher` using whatever "injection" mechanism is available to you. Simplest is just a constructor:

```
public class Counter {
  private final CountFetcher fetcher; 

  public Counter(CountFetcher fetcher) { 
    this.fetcher = fetcher;
  }

  public getCounts() {
    Promise<Integer> count1 = fetcher.getCount1();
    Promise<Integer> count2 = fetcher.getCount2();
    ...
  }
}
```

In your production code, you instantiate `Counter` with a real `CountFetcher`. In test code, you inject a mock version of `CountFetcher` which can have each individual `getCountXXX` method return whatever you want:

```
public class MockCountFetcher extends CountFetcher {
  @Override
  getCount1() { return mockCount1; }
}

public class TestCounter {
  @Test
  public void smokeTest() {
    CountFetcher mockFetcher = new MockCountFetcher();
    Counter counter = new Counter(mockFetcher);
    assertEquals(someExpectedValue, counter.getCounts());
  }
}
```